# Kleene star proof: $(AA)^*$ is the set of strings from $A^*$ of even length

Tags: proof-verification, formal-languages

> Let $A$ be an alphabet.
>
> By $A^{**}$ let us denote the set of all strings from
>   $A^*$ of even length. (This definition may be incorrect but it was given to me in the question)
>
> Show that $$(AA)^{*} = A^{**}$$

***My Answer:***

I believe I need to show two cases, not sure if I proved the cases exactly correct.

1. $(AA)^{*} \subseteq A^{**}$
2. $A^{**} \subseteq (AA)^{*}$

case 1: Suppose $w \in (AA)^{*}$ then by definition of Kleene star $w$ will contain $0$ or more strings of $AA$ which means $w$ can be a string from $A^*$ since $A^*$ just repeats the string with a longer length and concatenation with two strings from $AA$ is the same as a string repeated with longer length so

$$w \in A^{**} \implies (AA)^{*} \subseteq A^{**}$$

case 2: Suppose $w \in A^{**}$ then $w$ is a $0$ or more strings from the alphabet $A$ and adding another Kleene star would make more combinations of the strings from $A$ with higher length which is the same as concatenating two strings to equal the same length so

$$w \in (AA)^{*} \implies A^{**} \subseteq (AA)^{*}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of your trouble with this problem seems to come from the poor choice of notation by the author: $A^{**}$ is not a good way to denote the set of even-length strings. Pre-empting the result we are asked to prove, one might suggest $A^{2*}$.

---

The key to understanding the theorem, as well as where you went wrong in your proposed solution, is to understand what a string of elements of $AA$ looks like.

The way you put it:

> concatenating two strings to equal the same length

suggests that you interpret $(AA)^*$ as being $A^*A^*$, i.e. the concatenations of two strings in $A$.

However, let us explicitly expand the definition of Kleene star:

$$(AA)^* = \{w_1 w_2 \ldots w_n: n \ge 0, \forall n: w_n \in AA\}$$

Now ask yourself the following questions:

- Would it be possible to construct e.g. the single-character string $a$ as an element of $(AA)^*$?
- What is the length of $w_1w_2\ldots w_n$?
- What are the elements of $(AA)^*$?

Comment: well a is not an element of (AA)* because (AA)* = (aa)* so it will contain all combinations of aa with higher length such as aaaa(length 2), aaaaaa(length 3), ..., so the elements of (AA)* would be 0 or more combinations of the string aa for example if a is a member of A in this case... is this correct?

Comment: It's very close. To round up, consider what other elements $AA$ has. E.g. $aa'a'a \in (AA)^*$ as well if $a, a' \in A$.

Comment: so the elements of AA would be anything in the alphabet concatenated as a string (which is usually repeated twice) so (AA)* would be 0 or more combinations of that string with higher length

Comment: Ok i see, so it would be different combinations of a,a' at different positions of the string but the same length... thanks for the help and the answer.

Comment: You're very welcome :).